# json data error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, json

How do I query this https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/book data.

I'd like to grab the open, maybe some other data and pass it into this.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/book',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
    $(Object.keys(data['close'])).each(function(index, key) {
      document.getElementById("stockprice").innerHTML = (data['close'][key].quote);
    });
    }
    });
}, 10000);
```

**Error:**

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>     at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
>     at Object.success ((index):84)
>     at u (jquery.js:2)
>     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
>     at k (jquery.js:2)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:2)
> ```

Comment: Hard to understand what you want to achieve... Please, provide some more info. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'd like to achieve being able to display https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/MSFT/book open price and other various json data entries. With my code above.

Comment: I don't really understand why you are looping through `data["close"]` if it's not an array. Only `asks` and `bids` are arrays, `quote` contains `open` and `close` properties.. Just access them like this `data.quote.open` or `data.quote.close`

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a `close` property on data, you may want to get this off of quote property, like so:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/book',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("stockprice").innerHTML = data.quote.close;
        }
    });
}, 10000);
```